# How to fix slot machine error

Tags: python, pygame

I had to design a slot machine for a class project and for some reason the program keeps crashing. I wasn't sure if there was something wrong if the code I put in or if I had missed something. We had been told only to use information from inventwithpython book in the red books using chapters 3,5,9. Any help with this code is greatly appreciated.

```
import random, sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()


WINDOWWIDTH = 1280
WINDOWHEIGHT = 720
BLACK = 0, 0, 0
BUTTONSIZE = 100
BUTTONGAPSIZE = 20
#Testing for Response with color:
GREEN = (255,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
clickedButton = ''
BASICFONT = pygame.font.SysFont('freesandbold.ttf',22)
FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

XMARGIN = int((WINDOWWIDTH - (2 * BUTTONSIZE) - BUTTONGAPSIZE) / 2)
YMARGIN = int((WINDOWHEIGHT - (2 * BUTTONSIZE) - BUTTONGAPSIZE) / 2)

# Rect objects for each of the four buttons
BLANKRECT = pygame.Rect(XMARGIN, YMARGIN, BUTTONSIZE, BUTTONSIZE)
MINUSRECT   = pygame.Rect(XMARGIN + BUTTONSIZE + BUTTONGAPSIZE, YMARGIN, BUTTONSIZE, BUTTONSIZE)
PLUSRECT    = pygame.Rect(XMARGIN, YMARGIN + BUTTONSIZE + BUTTONGAPSIZE, BUTTONSIZE, BUTTONSIZE)
SPINBRECT  = pygame.Rect(XMARGIN + BUTTONSIZE + BUTTONGAPSIZE, YMARGIN + BUTTONSIZE + BUTTONGAPSIZE, BUTTONSIZE, BUTTONSIZE)

WHEEL1 = ['Tree', 'Reindeer', 'Reindeer', 'Frosty', 'Frosty', 'Frosty', 'Santa', 'Santa', 'Santa', 'Santa']
WHEEL2 = ['Tree', 'Reindeer', 'Reindeer', 'Frosty', 'Frosty', 'Frosty', 'Santa', 'Santa', 'Santa', 'Santa']
WHEEL3 = ['Tree', 'Reindeer', 'Reindeer', 'Frosty', 'Frosty', 'Frosty', 'Santa', 'Santa', 'Santa', 'Santa']


IMAGELIST1 = [pygame.image.load('Tree.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Reindeer.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Reindeer.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Frosty.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Frosty.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Frosty.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Santa.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Santa.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Santa.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Santa.png')]


IMAGELIST2 = [pygame.image.load('Tree.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Reindeer.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Reindeer.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Frosty.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Frosty.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Frosty.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Santa.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Santa.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Santa.png'),
              pygame.image.load('Santa.png')]


IMAGELIST3 = [pygame.image.load('tree.png'),
              pygame.image.load('reindeer.png'),
              pygame.image.load('reindeer.png'),
              pygame.image.load('frosty.png'),
              pygame.image.load('frosty.png'),
              pygame.image.load('frosty.png'),
              pygame.image.load('santa.png'),
              pygame.image.load('santa.png'),
              pygame.image.load('santa.png'),
              pygame.image.load('santa.png')]

blank = pygame.image.load('blank.png')
minus = pygame.image.load('minus.png')
plus = pygame.image.load('plus.png')
spinB = pygame.image.load('spin.png')

topcoord = 50
leftcoord = 50
startTop = 50
startLeft = 50
w1 = 1
w2 = 1
w3 = 1
n = 1
funds = 500
winnings = 0
bid = 5
choice = 'yes'
TEXTCOLOR = WHITE

# load the sound files
TREE = pygame.mixer.Sound('Tree.ogg')
REINDEER = pygame.mixer.Sound('Reindeer.ogg')
FROSTY = pygame.mixer.Sound('Frosty.ogg')
SANTA = pygame.mixer.Sound('Santa.ogg')    

def intro(funds):
    print('would you like to spin?')
    funds = 500
    print('Funds: 500')
    return funds

def PlaceBid(bet, funds):
    while True:
        bet = input('How much would you like to bet? (1)5 (2)10 (3)15 (4)20')
        if bet == '1':
            bet = 5
            funds -= bet
            return bet, funds
        elif bet == '2':
            bet  = 10
            funds -= bet
            return bet, funds
        elif bet == '3':
            bet  = 15
            funds -= bet
            return bet, funds
        elif bet == '4':
            bet = 20
            funds -= bet
            return bet, funds
        else:
            print('That was an incorrect option.')
            continue

def drawButtons():
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, BLANK, BLANKRECT)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, MINUS, MINUSRECT)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, PLUS,  PLUSRECT)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, SPINB, SPINBRECT)

def PlusBet(funds, bid):
    bid += 5
    if bid > funds:
        bid = funds
        return bid
    elif bid > 20:
        bid = 20
        return bid

def MinusBet(funds, bid):
    bid -= 5
    if bid < 5:
        bid = 5
        return bid

def Spin(word1, word2, word3):
    n = random.randint(0,9)
    word1 = WHEEL1 [n]
    image1 = IMAGELIST1[n]
    n = random.randint(0,9)
    word2 = WHEEL2 [n]
    image2 = IMAGELIST2[n]
    n = random.randint(0,9)
    word3 = WHEEL3 [n]
    image3 = IMAGELIST2[n]

    print(word1 + ' ' + word2 + ' ' + word3)
    return word1, word2, word3, image1, image2, image3

def DisplayImage(DISPLAYSURF, image, topCoord, leftCoord):
    imageRect = image.get_rect()
    imageRect.top = topCoord
    imageRect.left = leftCoord
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(image, imageRect)
    leftCoord = imageRect.right + 10
    return leftCoord

def DisplayMinus (DISPLAYSURF, minus):
    minusRect = minus.get_rect()
    minusRect.top = 450
    minusRect.left = 50
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(minus, minusRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    minusButton = minusRect
    return minusButton

def DisplayPlus (DISPLAYSURF, plus):
    plusRect = plus.get_rect()
    plusRect.top = 450
    plusRect.left = 250
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(plus, plusRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    plusButton = plusRect
    return plusButton

def DisplaySpin (DISPLAYSURF, spinB):
    spinRect = spinB.get_rect()
    spinRect.top = 450
    spinRect.left = 500
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(spinB, spinRect)
    pygame.display.update()
    spinButton = spinRect
    return spinButton

def DisplayFunds(DISPLAYSURF, funds, WHITE, BASICFONT):
    fundsSurf = BASICFONT.render('Funds: ' +str(funds),1,WHITE)
    fundsRect = fundsSurf.get_rect()
    fundsRect.top = 100
    fundsRect.left = 675
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(fundsSurf, fundsRect)
    pygame.display.update()

def DisplayWinnings(DISPLAYSURF, winnings, WHITE, BASICFONT):
    winningsSurf = BASICFONT.render('Winnings: ' +str(winnings),1,WHITE)
    winningsRect = winningsSurf.get_rect()
    winningsRect.top = 150
    winningsRect.left = 675
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(winningsSurf, winningsRect)
    pygame.display.update()

def DisplayBet(DISPLAYSURF, bet, WHITE, BASICFONT):
    betSurf = BASICFONT.render('Bet: ' +str(winnings),1,WHITE)
    betRect = betSurf.get_rect()
    betRect.top = 475
    betRect.left = 165
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(betSurf, betRect)
    pygame.display.update()



**def GetButtonClicked(x,y):
    if minusButton.collidepoint((x,y)):
        return 'minusBet'
    if plusButton.collidepoint((x,y)):
        return 'plusBet'
    if spinButton.collidepoint((x,y)):
        return 'spin'**

def Terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def ReturnWinnings(word1, word2, word3, bank, bid):
    if word1 == word2 and word1 == word3:
        if word1 == 'Tree':
            sound = TREE
            winnings = bid * 5
            bank += winnings
            return bank
        elif word1 == 'Reindeer':
            sound = REINDEER
            winnings = bid * 4
            bank += winnings
            return bank
        elif word1 == 'Frosty':
            sound = FROSTY
            winnings = bid * 3
            bank += winnings
            return bank
        elif word1 == 'Santa':
            sound = SANTA
            winnings = bid * 2
            bank += winnings
            return bank
    else:
        return bank


funds = intro(funds)
DISPLAYSURF.fill(GREEN)
leftcoord = DisplayImage(DISPLAYSURF, blank, topcoord, leftcoord)
leftcoord = DisplayImage(DISPLAYSURF, blank, topcoord, leftcoord)
leftcoord = DisplayImage(DISPLAYSURF, blank, topcoord, leftcoord)
minusButton = DisplayMinus(DISPLAYSURF, minus)
plusButton = DisplayPlus(DISPLAYSURF, plus)
spinButton = DisplaySpin(DISPLAYSURF, spinB)
DisplayFunds(DISPLAYSURF, funds, WHITE, BASICFONT)
DisplayWinnings(DISPLAYSURF, winnings, WHITE, BASICFONT)
DisplayBet(DISPLAYSURF, bid, WHITE, BASICFONT)

while True:
    bid, funds = PlaceBid(bid, funds)
    w1, w2, w3, i1, i2, i3 = Spin(w1, w2, w3)
    topcoord = startTop
    leftcoord = startLeft
    funds = ReturnWinnings(w1, w2, w3, funds, bid)
    leftcoord = DisplayImage(DISPLAYSURF, i1, topcoord, leftcoord)
    leftcoord = DisplayImage(DISPLAYSURF, i2, topcoord, leftcoord)
    leftcoord = DisplayImage(DISPLAYSURF, i3, topcoord, leftcoord)
    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(30)
    print(funds)
    choice = input('Would you like to play again?')
    if choice.lower().startswith('y'):
        continue
    else:


break
```

Comment: Define "crashing". Is it crashing your computer? Is it throwing a python error? What error?

Comment: As the program is crashing you should investigate diagnostic and debugging facilities to find out where in the program the crash is occurring. When you know which line the crash occurs on you should be able to work out why it crashes.

Comment: Can you higghlight code which is failing?

Comment: What message does the game crash with?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is intentional or not, but it looks like your file names in your IMAGELIST1 and 2 start with an uppercase letter (i.e. 'Santa.png') while the ones in IMAGELIST3 start with a lowercase letter (i.e. 'santa.png').

when your program gets to the ReturnWinning function there doesn't seem to be anything for lowercase letters. that could be your problem. try that and see if it works.

Comment: The python code itself doesn't cause an error, it's when it launches pygame, the pygame program freezes and doesn't response the second I try to press the spin button. I think the error is coming from this part of the I have bolded with **.

Comment: Is this the entire code or are there other parts? Because the part you have the asterisks by is not called anywhere in the program, so I don't know if it really is the problem or not.